# I want to randomly select items from a list and add them to another list without replacement

Tags: python, list, random, sample

I'm trying to randomly select items from a list and add them to another list.

The list of elements I'm choosing from looks like this:

```
data=[2,3,4,7,8,12,17,24,27,33,35,36,37,38,40,43,44,50,51,54]
```

I want to randomly take an element from this list and add it to one of four lists until each list has the same number of elements.

```
lists=[[1,'x','x','x','x','x'],[3,'x','x','x','x','x'],[5,'x','x','x','x','x'],[7,'x','x','x','x','x']]
```

I have tried using random.choice but this gives me duplicates:

```
def fill_lists(data):
for list in lists:
    for n,i in enumerate(list):
        if i=='x':
            list[n]= random.choice(data)
```

I want my function to return a list that contains 4 lists each containing a random sample of the data list with no duplicates.  I also want the first element of each list to be a value that I have already placed into the list.

Comment: Randomize/shuffle the values in data first and then start filling the lists

Comment: You are scrambling the data and splitting it.Not sure how to do it in Python but I'm sure there's a translation for `split(sample(data), rep(1:4, 5))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
data=[2,3,4,7,8,12,17,24,27,33,35,36,37,38,40,43,44,50,51,54]
random.shuffle(data)
lists = [data[i:i+len(data)/4] for i in range(0, len(data), len(data)/4)]
print(lists)
```

Randomly pulling from your initial list will have the same effect as shuffling  then pulling in order. Splitting  into sublists can then be done. If you need the sublists sorted, just map sort over the list afterwards.

You can change the number of groups by altering the divisor of `len(data)/4`

Edit: I missed this part of your question:

```
heads = [1,3,5,7]
[q.insert(0,p) for p,q in zip(heads,lists)]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to put the values in a new list, so list = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]

Comment: I am putting the values into a new list. I assumed the old list could be discarded, but if that's not the case then he or she could copy data before shuffling.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just trying to match the OPs naming to give the same result as the example

Comment: @dashiell Is this Python2.x or Python3.x? This code doesn't work in Python3.x but the way you're printing indicates Python3.x

Comment: I want to be sure when edit the lists I can keep the first element of the list to be a preselected value.

Comment: @ted I tested it in Python 2, and if it's not working in Python 3 it's likely because the result of the division is a float. The fix is to use integer division with `//`.

Comment: @dashiell In that case, shouldn't you use ´xrange()´ instead of ´range()´?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample`:

```
 data=[2,3,4,7,8,12,17,24,27,33,35,36,37,38,40,43,44,50,51,54]
 random.sample(data, 5)
 # [27, 12, 33, 24, 17]
```

To get a nested list of it, use a list comprehension

```
 [random.sample(data, 5) for _ in range(5)]
 # [[40, 35, 24, 54, 17],
 #  [17, 54, 35, 43, 37],
 #  [40, 4, 43, 33, 44],
 #  [51, 37, 35, 33, 8],
 #  [54, 4, 44, 27, 50]]
```

Edit: The above won't give you unique values; you should accept the above answer for the unique values. I interpreted the question wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, modifying the ranges inside the `d` function to tune to the number elements you want.

```
import random

def f(data):
    val = random.choice(data)
    ix = data.index(val)
    data.pop(ix)
    return val, data

def d(data):
    topholder = []
    m = len(data)/4
    for i in range(4):
        holder = []
        for n in range(m):
            holder.append(f(data)[0])
        topholder.append(holder)
    return topholder

d(data)
```

This will always give you 4 lists of randomly sampled values without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

another shuffle based but ensuring the all sub lists have the same size in case number of elements is not divisible to number of lists (try 7 for example).

```
from random import shuffle

def split(data, n):   
    size=int(len(data)/n);
    for i in range(0, n*size, size):
        yield data[i:i+size]


data=[2,3,4,7,8,12,17,24,27,33,35,36,37,38,40,43,44,50,51,54]
shuffle(data)
list(split(data, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic function that returns a list of list where each list starts with a specified value. The amount of nested lists is determined by the amount of *starting_values*.

```
import random

def get_random_list(element_list, starting_values, size_per_group):
    num_of_groups = len(starting_values)
    size_per_group -= 1
    total_elements = num_of_groups * size_per_group
    random_data = random.sample(element_list, total_elements)
    return [[starting_values[x]] + random_data[x * size_per_group:(x + 1) * size_per_group] for x in range(num_of_groups)]

data = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 17, 24, 27, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 43, 44, 50, 51, 54]

print(get_random_list(data, starting_values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], size_per_group=2))
# OUTPUT: [[1, 36], [2, 54], [3, 17], [4, 7], [5, 35], [6, 33]]
print(get_random_list(data, starting_values=[9, 3, 5], size_per_group=6))
# OUTPUT: [[9, 54, 2, 7, 38, 24], [3, 35, 8, 37, 40, 17], [5, 44, 4, 27, 50, 3]]
```

It works for Python2.x and Python3.x but for Python2.x you should change `range()` to `xrange()` for better use of memory.